# Stop mount/unmount, keep component alive by preventing unmount

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an desktop application where I get continuous sensor data stream, I have tabs to visualize the data. The general layout is as shown in the figure below.

[Layout of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPPjv.png)

```
Current structure:
index.jsx/ 
   /Component A
   /Component B
   /Component C
```

index.jsx has the selector menu and selects based on the tab selected.

When I switch to the tabs for data visualization, My component A which gets the continuous data gets unmounted and remounted when I switch back to it. Is there any way to prevent this ?? So that I can keep my component alive even when I am switching tabs and have continuous data steam available.

I there any way to accomplish this in react ?

Comment: Do you use a react lib for these tabs? Most of them has a prop that decides if it should unmount or not.

Comment: @ChristianMoen No, I do not use any external libraries, they are selected based on ID (0, 1, 2) and relevant component is loaded.